# Change workflow default state with hook_form_alter()

Tags: 7, forms, workflows

How can I programmatically access and alter the [Workflow](http://drupal.org/project/workflow) module settings with `hook_form_alter()` on a node edit form?

I can see the Workflow] module settings in its own field-set on the node edit form, but I cannot find any mention of it when I look at the output of `dd($form)`, `dd($form_state)`, or `dpm($form)`.

I would have expected to find it somewhere similar to the following.

```
$form['edit_workflow']['value'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$form['workflow'] is accessible using [#after_build](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#after_build) within the [Form API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7).

```
function hook_form_alter($form, &$form_state) {
    $form['#after_build'][] = '_manage_workflow';
}

function _manage_workflow($form, &$form_state) {
    $form['workflow'] = ''; //Do workflow alterations here...
    return $form;
}
```

Comment: I figured this would work in D6 as well, but setting a #default_value on the workflow never seems to work. Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your implementation of [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) runs before the one provided by the [Workflow](http://drupal.org/project/workflow) module. Implement [hook_module_implements_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7) to change the order in which implementations of [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) are executed. Alternatively, give your module a higher weight than the [Workflow](http://drupal.org/project/workflow) has.

Beware that this approach does not work for changing the order of implementations of [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) specifically. Implementations of [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) are always executed in the same order as those of [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7). This is due to the way how [drupal_prepare_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_prepare_form/7) calls [drupal_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/drupal_alter/7).